# How to Toggle Selection of Multiple Polygons within a single KML file in OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have a KML file with around 8-9 polygons contained within. For more information about these polygons when clicked a popup appears. Some of these polygons overlap entirely which when clicked will on select of the the overlapped regions.

I want to be able to select then polygons hidden underneath the polygons on top. I am wondering if there is a way to have it toggle selected polygon each time the place is clicked or even how KMLs with multiple polygons are handled in OpenLayers.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is more suitable for https://gis.stackexchange.com/

Have a look at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29223/dealing-with-overlapping-features-in-openlayers

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't figure out how to phrase my search properly. You have been a big help.